# Within an XSD file, what does the pattern [ !-~]* actually check for?

Tags: regex, xsd

I've searched far and wide and have yet to find anywhere that explains the Regular Expression: `[ !-~]*` or, for that matter `([!-~]|[ ])*[!-~]([!-~]|[ ])*`

I've used multiple RegEx testers and they seem to accept all input. I've read that XSD's accept a unique form of RegEx and doesn't accept all RegEx statements, so, this may not be a standard RegEx expression (I don't believe it is). The only hint I have is that the Type name is `an` for the first expression and `anM` for the second. I believe, to some extent, this is an abbreviation for alpha numeric and alpha numeric Multiple but I want to be 100% sure what this is really accepting and not make assumptions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[ !-~]` matches a space or any character in the range from `!` to `~`, where range is defined by the ASCII/Unicode order. Incidentally, `!` is the first and `~` the last printable ASCII character, so it will match any printable ASCII character or a space.

`([!-~]|[ ])*[!-~]([!-~]|[ ])*` Is similar, but it requires one non-space character. `[!-~]|[ ]` is the same as `[ !-~]`.

Comment: also `([!-~]|[ ])` can also be written as `[ -~]` since space is what you want to include

Comment: @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It yes good point! But this obfuscates the regex even further (in my opinion) and the question was about an explanation of the regex and not how to optimize it ;)